# Can not get params from URL - why is my cgi.FieldStorage() empty?

Tags: python, parameters, cgi, parameter-passing

I cant get parameters from URL. After reading numerous posts on the web but nothing seems to answer my question...

I have a simple HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
    <form action="test.py" method="get">            
        Name: <input id="person_name" type="text" name="person_name" >          
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" >        
    </form>     
</body>
```

and my python script looks like this:

```
import cgi, cgitb   

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
name = str( form.getvalue('person_name') )

print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")    
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("Hello " + name )
print("<br/>")
print ("all params: " + str(form)  )
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

However, when I execute the HTML file and type "Mike" as a name, my python script prints:

```
Hello None
all params: FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

the cgi.FieldStorage() is empty.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Try changing your form's method to `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say.

`<form action="test.py" method="get">` Error?

It should be `<form action="cgi-bin/test.py" method="get">`

If "cgi-bin" is not a part of the url sgi scripts are not executed. It's even surprising that you get some kind of response.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to cgi-bin/tet.py and put the test.py file in that directory. However, I get "500 Internal server error"

Answer (score 0):

> I get "500 Internal server error"

It's better now. It looks like it is starting working. The problem is that your python script has no declaration. It starts with `import cgi, cgitb` when it should start with `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Apache doesn't know what kind of script it is.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding each of these 2 options, also tried putting the file in the same directory or in "cgi-bin" (i.e. tried all the possible 4 variations). But it does not works. I get the same results ( i.e. when file is in the same directory: I get "None". When file test.py is in "cgi-bin" , I get "500 Internal server error")

Answer (score 0):

the 500 internal server error is a problem with your apache script configuration file especially the pythonhandler and addhandlers area something to do with mod-python